# Can I recreate a jpeg from a vector with class "raw"?

Tags: r

I've been able to use an API to download a file to R...sort of.  I download the file and receive a vector of class "raw", but what I would like to do is write that vector out to a file in a manner that recreates the file as it was uploaded to my site.

In the sample vector below, I have a jpeg that I would like to save to a file.  However, the solution needs to be more arbitrary, as pretty much any type of file could be downloaded via the API.

[The vector I'm working with is rather large, so I'm linking to it.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1arPeQm2agln-V4d_5_jULJbhtWIb7KdLtX45UWsCKBM/edit?usp=sharing)

I suppose you could use whatever file name you want, but the file name as downloaded from the site can be accessed using
    gsub("\"", "", attributes(file)$'Content-Type'[2])

My initial thought was to convert the raw to bits using `rawToBits` but I can't seem to recreate the jpeg from there.  Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by " in a manner that recreates the file as it was uploaded to my site.".  What has changed since you downloaded it to R?

Comment: The image that was originally uploaded was [this lovely picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw3leA1Ef_e5aFkyWDJ3Vjh4NTg/edit?usp=sharing). The image was uploaded to a record in a [REDCap](http://www.project-redcap.org) database. When I download the file through the API, I get the raw vector in the link in my question.  It appears to be some kind of a HEX representation of the internal contents of the file. What I'd like to do is write the raw vector into a folder so that I can open the file and see the picture.  (Preferably with a process that can be used on any file type). @AndreMichaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on trial and error.

```
writeBin(as.vector(file), 
         gsub("\"", "", attributes(file)$'Content-Type'[2]),
         useBytes=TRUE)
```